# Android maps v2 orientation change show blank screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I haven an activity with a navigation drawer.
The map is shown inside a fragment that contains some other controls.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/incident" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/notify_work" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the first loading everything it's ok, but when I change the orientation in emulator only a blank screen with the toolbar and buttons is shown to me.
I'm using maps v2 with extended library.

Follow the fragment code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap mCurrentMap = null;
    private static MapFragment mapFragment;
    private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;

    public static MapFragment newInstance() {
        if(mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = new MapFragment();
            mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        }
        return mapFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if(supportMapFragment != null) {
            if(supportMapFragment.getExtendedMap() != null) {
                mCurrentMap = supportMapFragment.getExtendedMap();
            }
        }
        setupMapIfNeeded();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    private void setupMapIfNeeded() {

        if(supportMapFragment == null) {
            supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            supportMapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            FragmentTransaction tx = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tx.replace(R.id.map, supportMapFragment);
            tx.commit();
        }

        if(mCurrentMap == null) {
            supportMapFragment.getExtendedMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    mCurrentMap = googleMap;
                    setupMap();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void setupMap() {

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);
        mCurrentMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mCurrentMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));
        mCurrentMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                .position(sydney));
        mCurrentMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-23.5526, -46.6422)));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The orientation works fine now.
I changed the FrameLayout view in xml to:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.androidmapsextensions.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And I removed the piece of code where the supportMapFragment was instantiated.